# what is this specific ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

So I'm constructing an isomorphism and I need a general form of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/({X^2-m})$

I'm not too sure what this means, but I think it is a ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by ${X^2-m}$? I can be completely wrong. Please clarify for me. Thank you

Comment: It's the *quotient* of ${\bf Z}[X]$ by the *ideal* generated by $X^2-m$.

Comment: What specifically does "this" refer to?

Comment: If you are familiar with long division of polynomials, then you should be able to convince yourself that the elements of the quotient ring you are looking at are the possible remainders when a polynomial with integer coefficients is divided by $x^2-m.$ In the quotient, the addition and multiplication are done $\mod x^2-m.$

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a ring and $r$ is an element of $R$, then the set $\{ar\mid a\in R\}$ is an ideal of $R$ (check this for yourself if it's not immediately obvious), and we typically denote this ideal by $(r)$ (or sometimes $\langle r\rangle$) and call it the ideal of $R$ *generated* by $r$.

Comment: This doesn't address the question though

Comment: Are you inside OP's head and know exactly what they were trying to ask? Let's see if OP clarifies, because I took their question to be asking what $(X^2-m)$ is

Comment: It almost seemed to me that the OP has the impression that the quotient should somehow be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x].$ I'm not entirely sure what the question is supposed to be. I agree with Alex that we need some clarification.